# Wikidata Query Names of city in all languages

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I query a citiy with its population from wikidata. With the language service i get he label in the given language.

But i would like to get the cityname in all languages or at least in multiple languages at once . I tried to pass * as language but i don't get all citynames returned.

Do I have to make the query for each language once  ?

This is my query

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?city ?cityLabel ?population
WHERE 
{
  ?city wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q515 .
  ?city wdt:P1566 "2950157" .
  ?city wdt:P1082 ?population .

  SERVICE wikibase:label {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" .
  }
}
```

I also tried to just set to languages like this

```
 SERVICE wikibase:label {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" .
    bd:serviceparam wikibase:language "de" .
  }
```

but it returns

> Unknown error: Expected a variable in the object position to which to
>   bind the language.

Comment: In a single row or multiple rows per language?

Comment: doesn't matter just want them to check some translations. but would be important to now to which language which string belongs to.

Comment: According to https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikidata_query_service/User_Manual#Label_service , it should work

Comment: I don't get the error that you reported.

Comment: Otherwise, the plain SPARQL way is to use `rdfs:label` instead of the magic Wikidata SERVICE. `?city rdfs:label ?cityLabel`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is telling you that you have to bind the German tag to a variable (?cityGe) in the selection process.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?city ?cityLabel ?cityGe ?population
WHERE 
{
  ?city wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q515 .
  ?city wdt:P1566 "2950157" .
  ?city wdt:P1082 ?population .

  SERVICE wikibase:label {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" .
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "de" .
  }
}
```

However, this does not solve your problem because this is only a fallback mechanism. If it cannot find English then it gives you German label.There are some examples [here](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:SPARQL_query_service/queries/examples).

This can be simplified as follows with only one variable:

```
SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en,de" }
```

However, as AKSW points out, you can use rdfs:label for your problem:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?city ?label ?population
WHERE 
{
  ?city wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q515 .
  ?city wdt:P1566 "2950157" .
  ?city wdt:P1082 ?population .
  ?city rdfs:label ?label
    filter(lang(?label) = 'de' || lang(?label) = 'en')
}
```

Comment: Or even more compact with SPARQL 1.1: `filter(lang(?label) in ('de','en'))`